# How to impersonate a service account from a differnet project when creating a cloudrun in a workflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

A workflow fails to start due to permission denied error when trying to impersonate a service account from different project

given:

Projects:

- `project1`
- `project2`

Service Accounts:

- `sa1@project1` with roles:

  - `Workflows Admin`
  - `Cloudrun Admin`
  - `Service Account Token Creator`
  - `Service Account User`
- `sa2@project2`

Workflows:

A `workflow1` in `project1` (creates a cloudrun instance with `serviceAccountName=sa2@project2`)

Result:

```
{
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account sa2@project2 (or it may not exist).",
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
  },
  "code": 403,
  "headers": {
    "Alt-Svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "Cache-Control": "private",
    "Content-Length": "244",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Date": "Wed, 14 Sep 2022 10:53:24 GMT",
    "Server": "ESF",
    "Vary": "Origin",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-Xss-Protection": "0"
  },
  "message": "HTTP server responded with error code 403",
  "tags": [
    "HttpError"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#impersonate-parent-level) for managing service account impersonation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client is a huge corporate.
Therefore the project level configuration to switch service accounts across projects is disabled (`iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage` is `enforced` )

This is the root cause of my problem and I cannot change it.
More information is available here:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project

My work around:

I needed this this as it seemed the simplest way to access external BigQuery Dataset & Project.

Solution:
Export private key for `sa2@project2` and pass it as a secret to application layer.
Use the key file to imperosnate`sa2@project2` service account.

example:

`engine = create_engine('bigquery://project2', location="asia-northeast1")`

Answer (score 0):

The error message `"Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account sa2@project2` indicates that users need permission to impersonate a service account in order to attach that service account to a resource. This means that the user needs the [**iam.serviceAccounts.actAs**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#allow-impersonation) permission on the service account.

There are several predefined roles that allow a principal to impersonate a service account:

**Service Account User**

**Service Account Token Creator**

**Workload Identity User**

Alternatively, you can grant a different [predefined role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles), or a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles), that includes permissions to impersonate service accounts.

**Service Account User (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser):** This role includes the `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission, which allows principals to indirectly access all the resources that the service account can access. For example, if a principal has the Service Account User role on a service account, and the service account has the **Cloud SQL Admin role** `(roles/cloudsql.admin)` on the project, then the principal can impersonate the service account to create a Cloud SQL instance.

You can try giving a service account User role on the service account which is trying to create a cloud run instance.

Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas) for more information on impersonating service accounts.

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer. However my user has already had "Service Account User" and it didn't work.